# How to know what version of firefox is installed?

Tags: c++, windows

How do I programmatically determine the version of multiple web browsers (Chrome, IE, and Firefox) on the same machine with c++?

Comment: This doesn't look like a real question.

Comment: registry handling may be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

[How to get Version of the software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606787/how-to-get-version-of-the-software)

Answer (score 2):

Where those 3 different browsers store their version information may all be different. You would have to track down those locations and read them with you application.  Since you are doing this on a windows machine you may be in luck, they may all use the registry.

This might help.

[Javascript Browser Detect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Answer (score 0):

To detect installed browsers, you should read http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2009/04/03/0a-Finding-All-Installed-Browsers-in-Windows-XP-and-Vista-ndash3b-beware-64bit!0a-.aspx.
To get their versions, simply follow the code in [How to get Version of the software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606787/how-to-get-version-of-the-software). 
Hope this helps! :)